# How to parse JSON containing a property with different data types into a generic class in Scala?

Tags: json, scala, rest, generics, playframework

I have a json from an API response that looks like this:

```
[{
value: true(Boolean),
name: "xyz",
date: 11/12/2020
},
{
value: "abc"(String),
name: "djd",
date: 11/12/2020
}]
```

It basically has a similar structure but one of the properties(value) might contain different data types. How do I parse this response into a class? I am trying to do it like this but I am not sure how to write the MainData class. Any ideas?

```
trait Data[A] {
   val value: A
   val date: ZonedDateTime
   val name: String
}    

case class ClassA(
  value: Boolean,
  name: String,
  date: ZonedDateTime
) extends Data[Boolean]
    
case class ClassB(
  value: String,
  name: String,
  date: ZonedDateTime
) extends Data[String]

case class MainData(data: Seq[Data[A])
```

and in the response handler, something like this:

```
case rsp if 200 == rsp.status =>
        val response = rsp.body.as[MainData[A]]
```

Comment: Which JSON library are you using?

Comment: I am using play.api.libs.json

Answer (score 0):

You can create separate `Reads` instances for `ClassA` and `ClassB` and then use the appropriate one based on the type of `value` field. Something along these lines:

```
val aReads = Json.reads[ClassA]
val bReads = Json.reads[ClassB]

implicit val dataReads = new Reads[Data[_]] {
  def reads(json: JsValue) = (json \ "value") match {
    case JsDefined(JsString(_)) => bReads.reads(json)
    case JsDefined(JsBoolean(_)) => aReads.reads(json)
    case x => JsError(s"Unknown data type: $x")
  }
}
```

This way your `json.as[Data[_]]` or `json.as[MainData]` will pick up `dataReads` which in turn will invoke the correct instance.
Alternatively, you don't have to use separate `aReads` and `bReads` readers at all and fully implement the `read(...)` method:

```
implicit val dataReads = new Reads[Data[_]] {
  def reads(json: JsValue) = {
    val name = (json \ "name").as[String]
    val date = (json \ "date").as[ZonedDateTime]
    (json \ "value") match {
      case JsDefined(JsString(str)) => JsSuccess(ClassB(str, name, date))
      case JsDefined(JsBoolean(bln)) => JsSuccess(ClassA(bln, name, date))
      case x => JsError(s"Unknown data type: $x")
    }
  }
}
```